# Websites are not loading in Firefox, but work in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, firefox

I am unable to access internet through Firefox 7.0.1. It is working fine on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Here's what I know:

- I don't receive any error messages. The page is loading, loading, loading and loading.
- It affects all sites
- I don't have any proxy server set up in Firefox

Comment: What error message do you get? Please refine your question!

Comment: no error messages as such.. just problem loading page :(

Comment: What sites are affected, or are all sites not loading?

Comment: all sites are affected. and no proxy servers as well.

Comment: sorry, it is just connecting connecting and connecting... even problem loading page does not come..

Comment: I took the liberty to add that to the question, so we all know what your situation is without having to read through the comments. (Pinging @Ranon)

Comment: Please run in safe mode (`firefox.exe -safe-mode`) and in new profile (`firefox.exe -ProfileManager`) and see if anything changes.

Comment: thanks jakub.gieryluk. It works in safe mode.. And I opened again in normal mode and the pages load properly. no issues :)

Comment: @jakub.gieryluk so post it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

- in safe mode (`firefox.exe -safe-mode`),
- and/or in new profile (`firefox.exe -ProfileManager`).

Answer (score 0):

Just reset Firefox and try again, you will loose settings : 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings#